# How do I install libksba on mac osx?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

According to rvm requirements, "For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'"

I am completely new and am not familiar with terminal commands. How can I install libksba without using homebrew?

Please help!!!

Comment: you need to install homebrew or macports

Answer (score 10):

I just installed libksba and its dependency libgpg-error from source and I can assure you that [installing Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation) and then installing libksba is much more straightforward. With Homebrew, you'll spend far less time dealing with terminal commands and the likelihood of success is considerably higher. It is popular for a reason.

For the benefit of future visitors, here are instructions to compile and install libgpg-error and libksba from source via bash without Homebrew:

```
cd /usr/local/src

curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.9.tar.gz
tar -xvf libgpg-error-1.9.tar.gz
cd libgpg-error-1.9/
./configure
make
make install

cd ..
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.2.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf libksba-1.2.0.tar.bz2
cd libksba-1.2.0/
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Homebrew isn't entirely trivial either. You need to have Xcode for Homebrew to work, apparently. So to get Ruby I need libksba, to get libksba I need homebrew, and to get homebrew I need Xcode. These dependencies are a bit tiresome.

Comment: Oh, and to get Xcode, you need an Apple login, and Apple's system is completely broken. I cannot get in. Are all those insane dependencies really necessary?

Comment: It gets worse -- `/usr/local/src` does not even exist on my Mac.

Comment: @SmilinBrian Create it: `mkdir -p /usr/local/src` The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) (read: file system best practices) has the following to say about `/usr/local`: "The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is updated."

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the command line tools of xcode. Then you don't need to install libksba.

http://blog.salientdigital.com/2012/05/16/how-to-fix-no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-on-mac-os-x-lion/

Best,
Olli