# Homebrew says Download failed when trying to install libksba

Tags: rvm, homebrew

In rvm requirements, I have `libksba`. So I try to install it with homebrew:

```
➜  ~  brew install libksba
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2

curl: (56) Recv failure: Operation timed out
Error: Download failed: ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2
```

Is there a way to fix this (by specifying additional repositories) ? Or [should I install the lib manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879629/how-do-i-install-libksba-on-mac-osx) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can

`rvm autolibs enable` and then

`rvm do what you want` (in my case: `rvm install 1.9.3`)