# Homebrew (Mac): cannot install libksba or dependency libgpg-error

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

I'm setting up a new Mac for development with Ruby on Rails. I have installed XCode (including command line tools), Homebrew, and RVM properly.  However, when I try to install the 2.0.0 Ruby version via RVM, I keep having to install libksba, which tries to install the dependency libgpg-error.  The log tells me it's downloading the file, but it never does anything. I've let it run for 30 minutes before and still doesn't do anything. The file is supposed to be a few hundred KB, so it's not very large...Below is the code I'm running:

```
$ brew install libksba
==> Installing libksba dependency: libgpg-error
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.11.tar.bz
```

This will just sit there and do nothing. Is there another repository where I can download the file from and manually install it?  It's frustrating to not be able to develop because of simple dependency errors.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the formulas associated with `libksba` and `libpgp-error`: [Homebrew Libksba Formula](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libksba.rb) and [Homebrew Libgpg-Error](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libgpg-error.rb). Try first updating `Homebrew`, since the discrepancy between the version shown in your logs and the one in the repo tells me is outdated:

```
brew update
brew install libksba
```

If that doenst work, then you can download it from here:

```
  url 'ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2'
  url 'ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.11.tar.bz2'
  mirror 'http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.11.tar.gz'
```

Comment: I updated Homebrew and it changed to a different build version. However, I still get the same results when I run `brew install libksba` where it doesn't download the file. Then I downloaded the mirror file and installed it via the 2nd answer (which references another question). It installs properly, but how do I tell Homebrew that the package is installed? When I do `brew list` libgpg-error doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the problem; my network is running through a 2nd router that was blocking FTP.  I skipped the 2nd router and connected to the primary router and `brew install libksba` worked just fine. Credit goes to fmendez who provided a mirror link that led me to check out the router ports for FTP.

For others coming to this question, the above instructions do work for manually downloading and installing the formulas. I also recommend checking out [Homebrew Tips n Tricks](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Tips-N%27-Tricks) for additional help on which commands to run.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following steps ( Ref from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879629/how-do-i-install-libksba-on-mac-osx) )

```
cd /usr/local/src

curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.9.tar.gz
tar -xvf libgpg-error-1.9.tar.gz
cd libgpg-error-1.9/
./configure
make
make install

cd ..
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.2.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf libksba-1.2.0.tar.bz2
cd libksba-1.2.0/
./configure
make
make install
```